# facebook.stream.addlike is not working in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Am trying to build an application using facebook sdk in silverlight.

In my application I need to send "like" for a post, to achieve this am using the following Async call:

```
_fb.Stream.AddLikeAsync(_dataAccess.Session.UserId, feed.stream_post.post_id, OnLikeCompleted, null);
```

which is giving an exception saying

> {Facebook.Utility.FacebookException: A session key must be specified
>   when request is signed with a session secret
>       at Facebook.Utility.Utilities.ParseException(String response, Boolean JSONFormat)
>       at Facebook.Rest.RestBase.OnRequestCompleted(Object sender, RequestCompletedEventArgs e)}

```
private void lnkLike_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var feed = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as StreamStory;

        MessageBox.Show(feed.stream_post.post_id.ToString());
        _fb.Stream.AddLikeAsync(_dataAccess.Session.UserId, feed.stream_post.post_id, OnLikeCompleted, null);

    }
    private void OnLikeCompleted(bool result, Object state, FacebookException e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("likes success")); 
            var actual = result;
        }
        else
        {
             Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>MessageBox.Show("Error: " +e.Message));
        }
    }
```

Please help me resolve the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using code from the Facebook Developer Toolkit that is nearly 3 years old. Facebook has changed their API many times since then. You need to reference Facebook's developer documents and consider using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org) which is compatible with Facebook's current API.